# How can invalid configuration values be hidden?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

The product configurator in Dynamics AX 2012 displays a [no symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) in the lookup of configuration attributes for invalid attribute values. Instead of displaying the no symbol, I would like to hide/filter the invalid values so that the user is only shown valid values in the lookup. How can I do that?

This question is for AX 2012 FP CU7, for R2/R3 I already found a solution. Problem is that the ProductConfiguration assembly was expanded in R2/R3 and now includes methods for testing attribute values. But FP CU7 does not include these methods (or at least I could not find any).